# Differentiating inside and outside a definite integral without partial differentation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

So the question is simply

$\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x^2+1})dx$

and

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 (\frac{1}{x^2+1})dx$

Would one simply just differentiate the inside and treat is as a regular integral and the other be simply equal to zero?

Comment: The first one can be evaluated using the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus): $\int_0^1 f'(x){\rm d}x = f(1) - f(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+1}\,{\rm d}x$$ is a real number. So $$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+1}\,{\rm d}x=0.$$The other quantity is the definite integral of another function, which happens to be non-zero. Note that $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+1}\,{\rm d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^2+1}\,{\rm d}t =\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y^2+1}\,{\rm d}y=\cdots$$so that  ${\rm d}/{\rm d}x$ has no relation whatsoever with the variable of integration (which is moot, since we're dealing with definite integrals).

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this:

$\frac{d}{dx}\big(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\big)= $
$\frac{d}{dx}\big($A number) $=0$

$\int_0^1 \big(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\big)dx=$ $\int_0^1$(A function of x) $\frac{d}{dx} \neq 0$ in general.

Comment: Alright thanks! That's how I thought to approach the first problem

Answer (score 0):

The other is certainly 0 just as you said .But remember 
            $int\_ 0^1 f'(x) =f(1)-f(0)$ (fundamental theorem of Calculus ).
So for f(x) = 1/(x^2 +1) , f(1)-f(0) = 1/2 -1=-1/2 .Stuart m.n.